# Calculate Mode in OpenCV (c++)

Tags: opencv, mode

Do you know how is the best and simply way to calculate the mode of a matrix??
For example in this matrix:

```
[1 1
 2 2
 3 3
 3 3]
```

The mode is 3... How can I calculate it?
THANKS!!!!